# Why isn't my included package being found?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, gateway

I am making a music discord bot. I am new to node.js. The code is the following:

```
const bot = new discord.Client()

var Gateway = require("@spectacles/gateway")
var gateway = Gateway.from("token",30)
const { Node } = require('lavalink');

const voice = new Node({
  password: 'youshallnotpass', // your Lavalink password
  userID: '803281789590306877', // the user ID of your bot
  host: 'lavalink.something.host', // a URL to your lavalink instance without protocol (optional, can be used instead of specifying hosts option)
  send(guildID, packet) {
    // send this packet to the gateway
    // you are responsible for properly serializing and encoding the packet for transmission
    return gateway.connections.get(Long.fromString(guildID).shiftRight(22).mod(this.shardCount)).send(packet);
  },
});

gateway.on('VOICE_STATE_UPDATE', (shard, state) => voice.voiceStateUpdate(state)); // forward voice state updates
gateway.on('VOICE_SERVER_UPDATE', (shard, info) => voice.voiceServerUpdate(info)); // forward voice server updates
gateway.on('GUILD_CREATE', (shard, guild) => {
  for (const state of guild.voice_states) voice.voiceStateUpdate(state);
});
```

The problem is that every time I run it I get this error:

```
TypeError: Gateway.from is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/container/Music-bot/index.js:5:23)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1076:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1097:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:941:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:782:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47)
```

The bot has been rate limited by YouTube and the only solution I have found is using Lavalink. Any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```js
var { Gateway } = require('@spectacles/gateway');
```

instead of

```js
var Gateway = require('@spectacles/gateway');
```

I've not used this library but am glancing at the doc [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@spectacles/gateway). I'm not entirely sure if this is the one you are using, but it is the only nodejs package that appears that I could find. If you're using another one, then please disregard this answer.

Comment: thats the library i am using, but this didn't solve it, i still get the same error